# A better way to write multiple in conditions?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have this code:

```
if 'value1' in record.actor or 'value2' in record.actor or 'pse-' in record.actor or 'value4' in record.actor or 'value5' in record.actor or 'value6' in record.actor or 'value7' in record.actor or 'value8' in record.actor or 'value9' in record.actor or 'value10' in record.actor or 'lastvalue' in record.actor:
  # some logic
```

Is there a succinct way to write this?

Comment: What about creating a list of your "values" and using a `for` loop to go over them?

Comment: `if any(v in record.actor for v in ['value1', 'value2', ...])`